# persist token even after the browser tab is closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The login token is being archived using local storage in the react. I want to keep the token intact even if I remove the browser's tab and delete the login information by removing the token when I remove the browser itself. Session storage cannot be used because information disappears when a tab is deleted Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localStorage instead. The API is the same. And it persists even after the tab is closed.

You could read the docs here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Yeah and the solution is to use `localStorage` instead. You cannot persist data with `sessionStorage` after the browser tab is closed. With `localStorage`, you can.

Comment: How can I delete my local storage data when my browser is closed?

Comment: My bad. I misread the question. You don't delete the token when the browser is closed. Normally whenever you're storing token in the web browser, you should store with an expiry date. Whenever the user closes the tab, the token remains in the browser, but the next time, the user goes into your site, you could check for the expiry of the token and add accordingly. Either delete the token itself or revalidate the token by sending it to the server. Normally, in the apps we build, we have a token with an expiry date, when the token expires, we logout the user.

Comment: I am currently using session storage and receiving and saving cookies. In fact, when the cookie is validated and expires after 15 minutes, it is sent to the login screen and the refresh token is saved back to session storage. Session storage deletes data when the browser is deleted, but local storage is not deleted unless it is deleted directly. If you use LocalStorage to close the browser while logged in, the local storage data remains. Is there any security problem with this? My boss wants to use session storage because the data in the local storage remains in the browser.

Comment: Not much actually. Just make sure, the expired token doesn't work in the server. If someone could hack your app by getting a token from the localStorage, they could pretty well hack it from the cookies too. Nothing much of difference there in terms of security.